# Using asynchronous method vs thread wait

Tags: c++, optimization, assembly

I have 2 versions of a function which are available in a C++ library which do the same task. One is a synchronous function, and another is of asynchronous type which allows a callback function to be registered.

Which of the below strategies is preferable for giving a better memory and performance optimization?

1. Call the synchronous function in a worker thread, and use mutex synchronization to wait until I get the result
2. Do not create a thread, but call the asynchronous version and get the result in callback

I am aware that worker thread creation in option 1 will cause more overhead. I am wanting to know issues related to overhead caused by thread synchronization objects, and how it compares to overhead caused by asynchronous call. Does the asynchronous version of a function internally spin off a thread and use synchronization object, or does it uses some other technique like directly talk to the kernel?

Comment: How are we supposed to guess how a library we have no information about and cannot see the source for is implemented? Just try using the both forms of the function and profile your program.

Comment: i am looking for a general approach to a typical asynchronous  function

Answer (score 2):

"Profile, don't speculate."  (DJB)

The answer to this question depends on too many things, and there is no general answer. The role of the developer is to be able to make these decisions. If you don't know, try the options and measure. In many cases, the difference won't matter and non-performance concerns will dominate.

"Premature optimisation is the root of all evil, say 97% of the time" (DEK)

Update in response to the question edit:

C++ libraries, in general, don't get to use magic to avoid synchronisation primitives. The asynchronous vs. synchronous interfaces are likely to be wrappers around things you would do anyway. Processing must happen in a context, and if completion is to be signalled to another context, a synchronisation primitive will be necessary to do that.

Of course, there might be other considerations. If your C++ library is talking to some piece of hardware that can do processing, things might be different. But you haven't told us about anything like that.

The answer to this question depends on context you haven't given us, including information about the library interface and the structure of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use asynchronous function because will probably do what you want to do manually with synchronous one but less error prone.

Asynchronous: Will create a thread, do work, when done -> call callback
Synchronous: Create a event to wait for, Create a thread for work, Wait for event, On thread call sync version , transfer result, signal event.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider that threads each have their own environment so they use more memory than a non threaded solution when all other things are equal.

Depending on your threading library there can also be significant overhead to starting and stopping threads.

If you need interprocess synchronization there can also be a lot of pain debugging threaded code.

If you're comfortable writing non threaded code (i.e. you won't burn a lot of time writing and debugging it) then that might be the best choice.